# Tooltip styling text gets hidden behind the <td>

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

I am creating a Datatable in which I have tooltip/Hover on each cell. The tooltip does not seem to appear completely if the text is too large. I am not able to style it accordingly. Can anyone help me on this?

**Or is there any better way I can add tooltip to DataTables with dynamic data**

Here is the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6e2L4hdt/)

CSS:

```
.tooltip1 {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip1 .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;

    /* Position the tooltip */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip1:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
for(var k=1;k<x.Data.length;k++){
    thisRow.push('<span class="tooltip1">' +x.Data[k].Value+ '<span class="tooltiptext">' + x.Data[k].Value+ '</span></span>');
  }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want tooltip to be in oneline for the long text, as i can see the complete tooltip wrapping?

Comment: @NagaSaiA Yes the tooltip is wrapping and thats fine. But its getting hidden behind the neighbouring <td> cell. Example: tooltip on Column B first row. When you minimize the screen table width you can reproduce this bug

Comment: remove position: absolute; to show long text- https://jsfiddle.net/Nagasai_Aytha/nnpjq80v/3/

Comment: how about defining where you want the tooltip to appear relative to the text, e.g. `left:0;top:10px;`. Also maybe get rid of the width and make the `padding:5px 10px;`

Comment: Nope @luke_mclachlan that din't work for me  :(

Comment: did you solve it in the end? what I mentioned worked for me with `position:absolute;` but it's difficult to know the solution because you haven't yet described your desired behaviour.

Comment: You could try a different library like qtip2: http://qtip2.com/ it adds the tooltip outside the table, thus easier to set z-index.